# Ajax loading content of same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I just copy paste the code form [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp)

In `load_second.php` I simply load gethint.php and rest of the code is same as in w3school.

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for modern browsers
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

gethint.php has this code`<?php echo "ghjghjghj";?>`

but when I run it on my local host it is not working properly.

I am using xampp. I run load_second.php on local host and following thing happens when I click on Change Content  [it display another Change Content button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdzEo.jpg)

Comment: your script please....

Comment: I have added the script

Comment: "// code for IE6, IE5" — Why?

Comment: It sounds like `gethint.php` doesn't contain what you think it contains. Try going to its URL directly in your browser's address bar.

Comment: gethint.php contains the same thing and it ouput "ghjghjghj" when I give URL of it directly in my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery's Ajax.
Its in my opinion way simpler.

```
$.get( "gethint.php", function( data ) {
   $( "#demo" ).html( data );
   console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: Thanks I install wordpress and then use jquery's ajax and it worked